# Put Line Below Icons In React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Here I have two icons and one dotted line. Currently, line is locating on top of icons. How to put icon in front and line behind icon?

```
<View style={styles.iconCompleted}>
      <Dash dashColor={'#57B9BB'} style={styles.dash}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
</View>
```

**Styles**

```
  iconCompleted:{
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height:200, 
  },
 dash:{
    width:1, 
    height: 180, 
    position: 'absolute', 
    top:0, 
    alignContent:'center', 
    alignSelf:'center',
    flexDirection:'column',
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place the line between the icons you can just use flexDirection: 'column'.

```
<View style={styles.iconCompleted}>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Dash dashColor={'#57B9BB'} style={styles.dash}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Dash dashColor={'#57B9BB'} style={styles.dash}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
      <Dash dashColor={'#57B9BB'} style={styles.dash}/>
      <Ionicons name='ios-checkmark-circle' size={32} color={'#57B9BB'}/>
</View>


        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            iconCompleted:{
            flexDirection: 'column',  
            alignItems: 'center',
            height:200, 
          },
         dash:{
            width:1, 
            height: 80, 
            top:0, 
            alignContent:'center', 
            alignSelf:'center',
            flexDirection:'column',
         },
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, check out please my source code again, I have added more icons.

Comment: Just add icon, dash, icon, dash... as many times as you need. Check the edit of my answer

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code, It looks like you want to connect two icons with a dotted line, But unfortunately the line get overlap, You can change the style as follows to connect two icons without line overlapping

```
iconCompleted:{
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height:200, 
    zIndex:10
},
dash:{
    width:1, 
    height: 200-(64), 
    position: 'absolute', 
    top:32, 
    alignContent:'center', 
    alignSelf:'center',
    flexDirection:'column',
    zIndex:9
},
```

If this fixed your reqirement, please comment, I can give an alterate solution if required

Comment: Still overlapping

Comment: Can you see my screenshot https://ibb.co/9bQJZPZ  , Do you need the same ?

Comment: Similar, check out please my source code again, I have added more icons.

Comment: In my above code could you please add style to icons as  iconz:{zIndex:99,backgroundColor:'#fff' }  Note: backgroundColor should be the color of your background also please adjust height values according to your requirement